# Matching pattern's nth occurence and delete until another multiple-brackets-expression pattern is found

Tags: string, shell, scripting, pattern-matching, text-processing

I want to write a shell script that will match the "%" character and delete everything until a specific char has been found. The specific char ranges in the `[A-G]`, `[a-g]`, `[m-n]`, `[p-s]` brackets. 
For instance, I would like to change `%0.h2d` to just `%d`.

I have reviewed many solutions up to now and I didn't find what I was looking for, especially concerning the multiple brackets. My initial plan with the code below was to first isolate the string and do the deletion afterwards:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i == "%") beginning=i; if($i == [ A-G ] || $i ==    [ a-g ] || $i ==[ m-n ] || $i == [ p-s ]) ending=i }; for (j=beginning;j<=endin    g;j++) printf $j" ";printf "\n" }' .annex/file.c
```

My code syntax is not right and what I get is a bunch of warnings:

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
    {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i == "%") beginning=i; if($i == >>>  [ <<<
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
awk: illegal statement at source line 1`
```

How could I modify this code or use another one to delete what's between `%` and `[A-G] || [a-g] || [m-n] || [p-s]` when `%` has been seen `n` times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
awk '{gsub(/%[^A-Ga-gm-np-s]+/, "%")} 1' .annex/file.c
```

#### Example

Consider this input file:

```
$ cat file.c
fprintf(stdout,"%-20s %0.h2d",a,b)
fprintf(stderr,"%.3f",c)
```

Let's run our command:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/%[^A-Ga-gm-np-s]+/, "%")} 1'  file.c 
fprintf(stdout,"%s %d",a,b)
fprintf(stderr,"%f",c)
```

#### How it works

`gsub(/%[^A-Ga-gm-np-s]+/, "%")` looks for any string that matches `%` followed by characters that are not in one of the ranges `A-G`, `a-g`, `m-n`, or `p-s` and replaces it with just `%`.

### Replacing the nth occurrence only

If you want to replace only the n-th occurrence, try:

```
sed -E 'H;1h;$!d;x; s/%[^A-Ga-gm-np-s]+/%/'"$n"
```

To replace, as an example, the second occurrence, use:

```
$ n=2; sed -E 'H;1h;$!d;x; s/%[^A-Ga-gm-np-s]+/%/'"$n"  file.c
fprintf(stdout,"%-20s %d",a,b)
fprintf(stderr,"%.3f",c)
```

To replace the third:

```
$ n=3; sed -E 'H;1h;$!d;x; s/%[^A-Ga-gm-np-s]+/%/'"$n"  file.c
fprintf(stdout,"%-20s %0.h2d",a,b)
fprintf(stderr,"%f",c)
```

You can use any value for `n` that you like.

#### How it works

- `-E` tells sed to use extended regular expressions (the kind that is the default for awk) not basic regular expressions.
- `H;1h;$!d;x;` tells sed to read the file into the pattern space.

  This series of commands reads in the whole file.  It is probably simplest to think of this as an idiom.  If you really want to know the gory details:

  - `H` - Append current line to hold space
  - `1h`  - If this is the first line, overwrite the hold space
    with it
  - `$!d` - If this is not the last line, delete pattern space
    and jump to the next line.
  - `x`  - Exchange hold and pattern space to put whole file in
    pattern space
- `'s/%[^A-Ga-gm-np-s]+/%/'"$n"` tells sed to replace the n-th occurrence of the pattern.

Comment: Very neat. Worked just fine, thank you. Where would you insert the increment for finding the nth occurrence of `%`?

Comment: @aboitier Thank you.  Also, I just added code to find and replace only the nth occurrence.

Comment: What an edit ! Off the charts. Thanks for all those gory details and this intro to sed -Extended